# Apache Spark: Using spark-submit 3x slower than running "standalone"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

I have a Maven project set up in Eclipse with an application that uses Apache Spark. The application does iterative steps to arrive at an answer. Eventually I want to deploy this on a cluster.

The problem is, when I run the program directly in Eclipse, the program's iterative section takes 57 seconds. When I run it using the `spark-submit.cmd` script, it takes 152 seconds! Why is this? Both are run with exactly the same configuration settings, with `local[*]` as master.

The effective command line for the Eclipse run is this huge line http://pastebin.com/5nybz1N3

The effective command for `spark-submit` is

`spark-submit --class org.comanche.yukon.Yukon yukonjar.jar`

Why is this? Could it be that `spark-submit` sets up some actual network connection and I'm getting a lot of latency? How can I find out?

I'm also getting `OutOfMemoryError`s from `spark-submit` but not the Eclipse run. Could this be related?

My only configuration is this, just as I create the `SparkContext`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("yukon")
        .setMaster("local[*]")
        .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0");
    jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    ....
```

I am using a system with 12 logical cores.

The JvM settings for eclipse is

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: My guess -- Eclipse keeps your `SparkContext` open. Whereas `spark-submit` creates a new `SparkContext` each time (hence being slower) Eclipse reuses it. Like I said -- just a guess -- but this would also cause the `spark-submit` to possibly run out of memory. The Eclipse `SparkContext` that is still running is chewing up RAM.

Comment: David, when ever we run the spark program its runs as a separate java process and eventually dies once the process is completed. Bobmax, Can you add the configurations with which you are trying to run? Like the executor memory, driver memory etc in both the cases. System configurations also matter as local[\*] on a quadcore CPU is different from local[\*] on a dual core CPU.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I have updated the info. The system has 12 logical cores.

Comment: What's your jvm settings for eclipse? Maybe you use more memory in eclipse.

Comment: Is it possible your spark-submit command is using a different version locally installed? From the pastebin, your eclipse is running 1.6.0.

Can you also post the full spark-submit command?

Comment: Thanks both of you. It is the same version 1.6, although indeed it is running on a separate installation (downloaded manually rather than with maven).